# Qt QML property binding and property change signal execution order

Tags: qt, qml

I cannot find information about the exact execution order of QML property bindings and property change signals.

For instance I have a property like:

```
property int myProp: 1000
```

Then I have another property bound to it:

```
property int myProp2: myProp
```

And I have property change signal handlers:

```
onMyPropChanged: console.log("myProp changed: ", myProp, " myProp2: ", myProp2)
onMyProp2Changed: console.log("myProp2 changed: ", myProp2, " myProp: ", myProp)
```

If I set myProp to 2 for e.g. the output is:

```
qml: myProp changed:  2  myProp2:  1000
qml: myProp2 changed:  2  myProp:  2
```

I don't know if it is a rule that the property change signal runs first then the dependent properties are going to be updated next, or their execution order is not defined at all. What happens if I have more dependent properties, is their re-evaluation order defined?

Then finally what about cross dependencies like:

```
property int myProp3: myProp2 + myProp
property int myProp2: myProp
property int myProp: 1000

onMyPropChanged: console.log("myProp changed: ", myProp, " myProp2: ", myProp2, " myProp3: ", myProp3)
onMyProp2Changed: console.log("myProp2 changed: ", myProp2, " myProp: ", myProp, " myProp3: ", myProp3)
onMyProp3Changed: console.log("myProp3 changed: ", myProp3, " myProp: ", myProp, " myProp2: ", myProp2)
```

On my machine the output is:

```
qml: myProp changed:  2  myProp2:  1000  myProp3:  2000
qml: myProp2 changed:  2  myProp:  2  myProp3:  2000
qml: myProp3 changed:  4  myProp:  2  myProp2:  2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals) say:

> If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected, when the signal is emitted.

But in QML, you don't really define things sequentially, so the order is really undefined.

In your first example, `myProp2` is bound to `myProp` which means it's connected to `myProp`'s onChanged signal. If any other properties are also bound to `myProp`, they will also be connected. But in what order? We can't tell.

So the moral of the story is you should not depend on the order of signals/slots in QML. Try to write your code in a way that the order does not matter.

Comment: Yes, makes sense for the slots. But what about the property changed handlers? Are they simply connected to the change signal as well so they are not distinguished in any way? Does this mean that it is possible that a binding is already updated when the property changed signal handler is executed? :O

Comment: `onMyPropChanged` is simply a slot that is automatically connected to the `myPropChanged` signal. So it's treated just like any other slot, because it IS a slot. I would think that yes, it is possible that other slots could have been called before this one because there's no way to specify the order that they are connected. Maybe in practice, you will normally see one called before another, but I would not recommend relying on that.